Deploying an Express app on Vercel with typescript
Im trying to deploy an express app built with typescript to vercel, the deployment succeeds, but there is some misconfiguration with the building of app on vercel i guess. My folder structure is like this.
folder structure
/project-root
├── /src
│   ├── /controllers
│   ├── /middlewares
│   ├── /routers
│   ├── /services
│   └── index.ts        <-- main entry point
│   └── express-app.ts  <-- Express app setup
├── /dist                <-- Transpiled code (generated after build)
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json

In the vercel dashboard for the deployment, i can see the source and output tabs like this, is this right, i have no idea??
.
I have added the relevent files code, Please help me with this process.
vercel json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "src/index.ts",
        "use": "@vercel/node",
        "config": {
          "typescript": {
            "tsconfigPath": "./tsconfig.json"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/dist/index.js"
      }
    ]
  }
  

package json
{
  "name": "pft",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json",
    "staging": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts --enable-source-maps --no-warnings --loader",
    "dev": "nodemon -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/index.ts --enable-source-maps --no-warnings --loader"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.10.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "tslog": "^4.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
    "concurrently": "^9.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.10",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }
}

index ts file
import "reflect-metadata";
require('dotenv').config();
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from "express";

const expressApp = require('./express-app');

const StartServer = async() => {

    // initialize the application server
    const app: Application = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    await expressApp(app);

    // listen to the application server on PORT
    app.listen(port, (): void => {
        console.log(`Express application server running on address => http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
}

if (process.env.VERCEL === '1') {
    module.exports = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        const app: Application = express();
        expressApp(app);
        app(req, res);
    }
} else StartServer();

